# listen to http requests of a Firefox tab with a plugin

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

Currently I am writing a plugin for Mozilla Firefox which is in need of the ability to listen to any http requests made by a tab. So I was reading the description of mdn's [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions/XUL_School/Intercepting_Page_Loads) about that topic, but I am not able to get it running.

I tried "The Easy Way" but I have no idea where to place this code. If I place it in the index.js of the plugin it just says "gBrowser is not defined" It would be really nice if someone could tell me how to get this running.

I also read this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Monitoring_HTTP_activity), which seemed similar to my problem of using XMLHttpRequest which I could get to work. So I tried to form this into the solution from this problem but it does not work either.

Thank you very much for any help :)

EDIT: I was able to form the code from the second article into the solution that worked for XMLHttpRequest like this:

```
let { Cc,Ci } = require("chrome");
var activityDistributor = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/http-activity-distributor;1"].getService(Ci.nsIHttpActivityDistributor);

var httpObserver = {
    observeActivity: function(aHttpChannel, aActivityType, aActivitySubtype, aTimestamp, aExtraSizeData, aExtraStringData){
        if (aActivityType == nsIHttpActivityObserver.ACTIVITY_TYPE_HTTP_TRANSACTION) {
            switch(aActivitySubtype) {
                case nsIHttpActivityObserver.ACTIVITY_SUBTYPE_RESPONSE_HEADER:
                    // received response header
                    break;
                case nsIHttpActivityObserver.ACTIVITY_SUBTYPE_RESPONSE_COMPLETE:
                    console.log('recieved !!!')
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
};

activityDistributor.addObserver(httpObserver);
```

But it does not do the log output (or at least I can't find it in the browser console).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, and it was just my fault. I named the variable wrong so the "nsIHttpActivityObserver" was not set ! So this would be the correct code:

```
let { Cc,Ci } = require("chrome");
var nsIHttpActivityObserver = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/http-activity-distributor;1"].getService(Ci.nsIHttpActivityDistributor);


var httpObserver = {
    observeActivity: function(aHttpChannel, aActivityType, aActivitySubtype, aTimestamp, aExtraSizeData, aExtraStringData){
        if (aActivityType == nsIHttpActivityObserver.ACTIVITY_TYPE_HTTP_TRANSACTION) {
            switch(aActivitySubtype) {
                case nsIHttpActivityObserver.ACTIVITY_SUBTYPE_RESPONSE_HEADER:
                    console.log('header received')
                    break;
                case nsIHttpActivityObserver.ACTIVITY_SUBTYPE_RESPONSE_COMPLETE:
                    console.log('complete anwser received')
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
};

nsIHttpActivityObserver.addObserver(httpObserver);
```